# How to define the variables passed by Javascript in the page dynamically using PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Here is my code where i have used the load function with auto refreshing the timing.php .

```
<script>
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function()
{ $('#myDiv').load('timing.php?test=<?php echo $test?>');
}, 1000);
</script>
```

My form is like,

```
<form id="formElem" name="formElem" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?> " method="get">
```

I wanna send the dynamic variable as,

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['view_det'])) 
{ 
$test=$row2['test_name'];
?>
<p id="myDiv"> </p>
```

pls help me .

Comment: Wait... So what is your problem? all you've shown us.. is your code but you haven't described what you actually expect to happen.

Comment: @Killrawr: Im sorry for dat. Actually im not getting the test variable into $test in timing.php with GET method. pls help me whats my wrong in the code. Thank u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
timing.php?test=<?php echo $test?>
```

This means that timing.php will be expecting a GET parameter called test. On timing.php, the parameter can be accessed like so:

```
<?php
$test = $_GET['test'];
```

Comment: But im not able to get the test variable from script to timing.php ...
whether am i correct in scripting the load function? or any missing... i could not understand where is my mistake... i totally strucked up since a day. pls help...